# looking for a verb meaning "to work to the extent less than you can"

Tags: word-request

Suppose you want to say to your employer or a recruiter that you always do your best. Is there any term to say that means **you do not try less than you can**?

In other words, how to fill the blank in the following sentence?

 I never .... = I always do my best.

 To be more clear, what is the verb that means "to work to the extent less than you can".

Comment: "Workers tend to *slack off* on Mondays and Fridays"

Comment: Probably not good language for an interview, but you could say you don't *half-ass* things. However, I would avoid saying "I don't ____" - I've heard there can be psychological effects where your brain doesn't really process the negating words such as "don't" or "never", and you (and any interviewer listening) subconsciously have the impression that it's not there , and that you do in fact ____.

Comment: @CowperKettle Thank you. Is it formal to be used in an interview?

Comment: _**slack**_ also _**slack off**_
to make less effort than usual, or to be lazy in your work as in
_He was accused of slacking and taking too many holidays._ Also
 
_**not pull your weight**_ meaning  _to not do your full share of work:_ as in
_He accused me of not pulling my weight._

Comment: being complacent carries the meaning if you use it in negative sentences.

Answer (score 2):

In an interview, it would be better to use a positive expression, for example

> I always give a hundred percent

Here is a reference: [give a hundred percent](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/give_a_hundred_percent)

If you really want a negative verb, you could consider [skive](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/skive) (very informal) and [shirk](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/shirk) (quite old-fashioned)